# Windows XP missing hal.dll error after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

**EDIT: The problem is due partitioning, most of the following might've not influenced the outcome.**

I was dual-booting and I wanted to make some unspecified partition space and I've decided I didn't really need my 14.04 Ubuntu so I deleted the partition of it with an Ubuntu Live CD. Since grub was on the partition (which I had forgotten), I ended up in grub rescue after a restart. I tried recovering grub without any Linux installed without luck so I've tried installing it again. It couldn't find partitions for some reason so I had to do a `fix-parts`. I "fixed" grub afterwards. The partition I deleted restored unintentionally so now I have 2 installs of Ubuntu.
And then for some reason I get an error for missing `hal.dll`. From what I've [found on the internet](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/missinghaldll.htm), it's probably a problem with `boot.ini`.

I compared windows `boot.ini` with `blkid` and everything seems fine:
`boot.ini`:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP
Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer
```

`blkid`:

```
/dev/sda2: LABEL="WindowsXP" UUID="3D2405657F4911EC" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="56917c5d-02" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="58916b24-685b-4453-b4e4-324e8fc48716" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="56917c5d-03" 
/dev/sda4: UUID="f9a7409d-f57b-4baa-81d6-e8ca7777781e" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="56917c5d-04" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="UbuntuHome" UUID="51403596-5042-4b3b-8efe-a26176c398df" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="56917c5d-05" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="NTFSDocs" UUID="6C638BF066930746" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="56917c5d-06" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="ac350524-a383-442b-8ed9-b39bbb7a6f4b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="56917c5d-07" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="FC41-5647" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e03a0436-01"
```

I know this is a rather obsolete problem since Windows XP is so old, but I hope I will receive help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it myself, the problem was that windows doesn't even see partitions it can't understand. Therefore Windows saw `sda2` as partition 1. Now the `boot.ini` looks like this (note the partition(1) instead of 2):

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP
Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /usepmtimer
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue. When I switched the boot device priority to my Ubuntu SSD, the `rdisk(0)` was no longer correct. I changed it to `rdisk(1)`. I've learned some new stuff about booting!